# Why does Facebook login ask for different (more) scopes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I want to trigger a Facebook login and I am accessing this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=398192236928167&scope=user_photos&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.useralbum.com/callback.html
```

I am specifying **scope=user_photos** but the permission popup says:

`App_name would like to access your public profile, friend list and photos`

and it used to just say

`would like to access your photos.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are doing nothing wrong**, the message

> App_name would like to access your public profile, friend list

appears along with your permission because Facebook adds the basic [Public Profile and Friend List permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) to all the apps as a default, even if you are not asking for any permissions. And you **cannot stop** Facebook from adding these basic permissions so that you may have permission request like

> App_name would like to access your photos.

**Edit:** if you request permission without defining any scope, accept it, then request another one with `scope=user_photos`, then it will just say `App_name would like to access your photos`.

Comment: ^This is what I found while looking for a fix on this issue, but I am 100% sure it just said this when I first started testing the app: `App_name would like to access your photos.` And I found it very neat.

Comment: That would have happened when you had already given the basic permission prior to adding the `user_photos` permission. After which it might have displayed `App_name would like to access your photos.`

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is what caused confusion. So if you trigger login without defining a "scope", accept it, then trigger another one with scope=user_photos, then it just says `App_name would like to access your photos`. Otherwise it will ask for profile, friends, photos on first prompt.